# python constructing functions on the fly

Tags: python

I have several little functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3` and a function `f`.

I want `f` to be a "container" to `f1`, `f2`, `f3`: to do the some of operations `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, depending on the program configuration (for example `f1` and `f2` or `f1` and `f3` or all the three) and nothing more.

I see two simple solutions: first to add some `if`'s in the function `f`:

```
if configuration_f1_f2:
    f1()
    f2()
```

second, I can add a list of operations in `f`:

```
for op in operations:
    op()
```

and add `f1`, `f2`, `f3` in `operations` or remove them, depending on configuration.

But can I somehow construct dynamically code of 'f' adding to it calls of `f1`, `f2` and `f3` exact what I need without any `if`'s or `list`'s or `for`'s? I mean something like on the fly code manipulation. So if my configuration is "`f1` and `f3`",  I set code of `f` so that it is

```
f1()
f3()
```

and when my configuration changes to "`f2` and `f3`" I modify code of `f` to

```
f2()
f3()
```

Can I manipulate the code of the function that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're brave, you can construct a function definition as a *string* and pass it to the [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) statement. For example:

```
func = "def f():\n"
if config_f1:
    func += " f1()\n"
if config_f2:
    func += " f2()\n"
exec func in globals()
```

At this point, you should have a new global `f()` that executes the appropriate bits of code.

Comment: Thank you! this seems to be the best solution!

Answer (score 3):

If `f1`, `f2` etc. are functions with side effects, than you should use an explicit `for` loop (no fancy `map` solution). Perhaps you want something like this?

```
configurations = {
  'config_1': (f1, f2, f3),
  'config_2': (f1, f2),
}

def f(config='config_1'):
    for op in configurations[config]:
        op()
```

If `f1`, `f2` etc. receive arguments, then perhaps this is a more suitable definition of `f`:

```
def f(config, *args, **kwargs):
    for op in configurations[config]:
        op(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create dictionary

```
fun_dict = {'f1': f1, 'f2': f2}
```

then parse your config and run function from dict:

```
fun_dict[parsed_name]()
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be various ways to achieve what you want, but for that you need to fully define the problem and context

a way could be like this, and most of the other will be variant of this, using a dict to lookup the function we need

```
def f1(): print "f1"
def f2(): print "f2"
def f3(): print "f3"

def f(fList):
    for f in fList: globals()[f]()

f(["f1", "f2"])
f("f1 f3 f1 f3 f2 f1 f3 f2".split())
```

Comment: why do you need a list of strings? this would work as well:

def f(*flist): [x() for x in flist]

f(f1, f2)

Comment: because OP was talking abt config, where values will be strings

Answer (score 1):

Use objects and the Command design pattern.

```
class Function( object ):
    pass

class F1( Function ):
    def __call__( self ):
        whatever `f1` used to do

 class F2( Function ):
    def __call__( self ):
        whatever `f1` used to do

 class Sequence( Function ):
     def __init__( self, *someList ):
         self.sequence= someList
     def __call__( self ):
         for f in self.sequence:
             f()

f= myDynamicOperation( F1(), F2(), F3() )
f()
```

That's how it's done.  No "constructing a function on the fly"

Comment: but how is it different from calling f1(), f2(), f3(); directly